# Access all the contents of an alias directory in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I created an alias directory by configuring the **httpd.conf** (main Apache configuration file) as follows:

```
Alias /farewell/ "D:/farewell/2/"
<Directory "D:/farewell/2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I want to access all the image files present inside the directory "**D:/farewell/2/**". For this, a **glob()** in PHP is recommended as follows:

```
<?php
 $path="farewell/*.*";
 $images=glob($path);
 foreach($images as $image)
     echo "<img src='$image' width='300'/>";
?>
```

But, the foreach loop doesn't follow, as **$images** acts as an empty array. Why is it so? 
The above code works well when accessing a physical folder present in the server htdocs folder.

For example,

```
<?php
        $path="images/*.*";
        $images=glob($path);
        foreach($images as $image)
            echo "<img src='$image' width='300'/>";
?>
```

This works really well as **images** is a folder present inside **htdocs** folder.

So, what is the procedure to access an alias directory?

Comment: You're making exactly the same mistakes as you were the first time you asked this question... plus some new ones.

Comment: @CD001 I'm sorry, am I supposed to delete this question as you already answered it in another post?

Comment: Nah it's fine - just bad SO etiquette to repeat the question; duplicates generally get locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php script does *not* access the directory via http but via the local file system. But the browser will access the resource(s) via http.

`$path="farewell/*.*";` That's a relative path (and mask). Unless your script is located at `"D:/` the path won't work.

```
<?php
$baseuri = '/farewell/';
$baselocal='D:/farewell/2/';

foreach(glob($baselocal.'*') as $path) {
    $fname = basename($path);
    echo '<img src="', $baseuri, $fname,'" width="300"/>';
}
```

The script "scans" D:/farewell/2/ but puts img elements with src attributes like `/farewell/image1.jpg` into the html document. Therefore the browser will request them with the same protocol (http/https) from the same host (localhost?) like e.g. `http://localhost/farewell/image1.jpg`. Your apache -because of the alias- will serve `D:/farewell/2/image1.jpg` as the result for that request.

Answer (score 0):

You mix two completely different things : Apache configuration and php. Just remember that php can run without Apache or without any webserver at all.

Alias directive "maps URLs to filesystem locations" ([doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)) and php glob() "finds pathnames matching a pattern". So you cannot give an URL to glob.

In order to access the alias directory from php, use glob with a path `glob("D:/farewell/2/*.*")` but your php must have rights to access to it, or call get_file_contents(www.example.com/farewell), and have fun parsing result…

Comment: how can we set the php to have access rights to the folder? i have set the folder to be shared by everyone.

Comment: @kamal0808 depends on your setup: file system permissions on directories and files, and open_basedir at least. You're on windows, which I do not know precisely. Did you try `glob("D:/farewell/2/*");` ? If result is empty, you lack permissions...